# Height 100% does not work properly when adding elements around my 100% height section

Tags: html, css

I apologize in advance for asking a question, that has been answered a thousand times before, but after an hour of researching I haven't found the answer to my problem yet.

I want a section of mine to have a height of 100%. And it works **perfectly fine** if I just use this code, Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/8m33jafw/

```
<section id="section-headline">
    <div id="frontpage" class="text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1 class="">We create Yada yada yada</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 cta-email">
            <form action="" method="POST" class="form-inline" role="form">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-md" id="" placeholder="Write your best Email here.">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md cta-green">Invite me to Beta!</button>
            </form>
            <div class="text-center">We <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> privacy</div>
        </div>


        <div id="icon-arrow" class="wow bounce icon-arrow" data-wow-iteration="3" data-wow-delay="2s">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-3x"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="section-subheadline">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h2>Let us stay in Touch!</h2>
                <img src="images/icons/twitter.png" alt="" class="icon-socialmedia wow rotateIn" data-wow-delay="1.0s">

                <img src="images/icons/google+.png" alt="" class="icon-socialmedia wow rotateIn" data-wow-delay="1.3s">

                <img src="images/icons/youtube.png" alt="" class="icon-socialmedia wow rotateIn" data-wow-delay="1.6s">

                <img src="images/icons/fb.png" alt="" class="icon-socialmedia wow rotateIn" data-wow-delay="1.9s">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h2>Subheadline with text</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus quam, quod facere, ipsam enim molestiae magnam! Pariatur vitae, doloribus aperiam.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem omnis, corporis suscipit odio vitae consequatur alias asperiores eligendi beatae tempore.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Suscipit modi quae earum tempora cum magnam enim eligendi necessitatibus, dicta, odio quia expedita corrupti tenetur voluptatem eius, numquam. Sit.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Quia excepturi, dolor nihil ut! Nostrum nisi commodi odit hic dicta maiores in asperiores iste obcaecati. Ex in, qui impedit.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

But after I add some elements around the section, the **markup breaks**. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/8m33jafw/1/

```
<div id="content" class="site-content">
    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <main id="main" class="site-main">
                <article id="post-4" class="post-4">
                    <div class="entry-content">

                        <section id="section-headline">
                            <div id="frontpage" class="text-center">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <h1 class="">We create the most transparent foundation there will ever be!</h1>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 cta-email">
                                    <form action="" method="POST" class="form-inline" role="form">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control input-md" id="" placeholder="Write your best Email here.">
                                        </div>

                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md cta-green">Invite me to Beta!</button>
                                    </form>
                                    <div class="text-center">We <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> privacy</div>
                                </div>


                                <div id="icon-arrow" class="wow bounce icon-arrow" data-wow-iteration="3" data-wow-delay="2s">
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-3x"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>

                        <section id="section-subheadline">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <h2>Let us stay in Touch!</h2>
                                        <img src="images/icons/twitter.png" alt="" class="icon-socialmedia wow rotateIn" data-wow-delay="1.0s">

                                        <img src="images/icons/google+.png" alt="" class="icon-socialmedia wow rotateIn" data-wow-delay="1.3s">

                                        <img src="images/icons/youtube.png" alt="" class="icon-socialmedia wow rotateIn" data-wow-delay="1.6s">

                                        <img src="images/icons/fb.png" alt="" class="icon-socialmedia wow rotateIn" data-wow-delay="1.9s">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <h2>Subheadline with text</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus quam, quod facere, ipsam enim molestiae magnam! Pariatur vitae, doloribus aperiam.</p>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem omnis, corporis suscipit odio vitae consequatur alias asperiores eligendi beatae tempore.</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Suscipit modi quae earum tempora cum magnam enim eligendi necessitatibus, dicta, odio quia expedita corrupti tenetur voluptatem eius, numquam. Sit.</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Quia excepturi, dolor nihil ut! Nostrum nisi commodi odit hic dicta maiores in asperiores iste obcaecati. Ex in, qui impedit.</p>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please I would appreciate any help with this. Thank you very much, here is the css I am using:

```
  html, body {
  height: 100%;
  }


nav.navbar.navbar-default {
  margin-bottom: 0px; }

section#section-headline {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-umgX2re73D4/UNJ8G_cQyQI/AAAAAAAAAPQ/eNACZypGlFQ/s1600/white-daisy-in-sunlight-wallpapers_1440x900.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #fff; }
  section#section-headline #frontpage h1 {
    padding-top: 10%;
    color: #8BC343;
    font-size: 5.79vw;
    font-family: 'Gafata', sans-serif; }
  section#section-headline #frontpage .cta-email {
    padding-top: 50px; }
  section#section-headline #frontpage .form-inline .form-control, section#section-headline #frontpage .form-inline .navbar-form, section#section-headline #frontpage .form-inline .navbar-form, section#section-headline #frontpage .form-inline .navbar-form {
    min-width: 250px; }
  section#section-headline #icon-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%; }

section#section-subheadline {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #fff; }
  section#section-subheadline img {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 20px; }
```

Unfortunately I have to consider those html elements. So please give me advice on how to get the 100% height on the first section.

Comment: Let me understand, you want your section-headline to be height:100%, which means the viewport (window) height?

Comment: Make sure that every element that wraps your `<section>` also has `height: 100%;`. That said, you seem to have *way too many* wrapping elements. `div div div main article div section div div` is a little bit like spaghetti :)

Comment: @denisol yes, I want the viewport height.

Comment: @misterManSam I know. Unfortunately Wordpress is wrapping these spaghetti elements around my posts. Whick kind of sucks, but I have to live with it, if I want to use underscores.me

Comment: Also, if you set the `height: 100%;` at the bottom of your CSS it will override any existing heights that are causing issues.

Comment: [Have a look at this example](http://jsbin.com/goqaf/2/edit), you can replicate the inline CSS in the external CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just changed one line in your css:

```
section#section-headline
{
    height:100vh;
}
```

This would give your section the hieght of the viewport, no matter what the content is.

And here is your **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8m33jafw/11/)**.

Please note that this is not supported in IE8 and older versions, for a complete list of supported browser check out [this link](http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seeing as you need to work with code spaghetti due to Wordpress, if the height is not critical and a collapsed height still gives acceptable results in outdated browsers - such as IE 6 - 8 - I would go with this method. It is far easier to maintain if you don't have to worry about every parents height.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/8m33jafw/9/)**

Here i'm adding a peace of CSS

```
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display: table;

}
```

And also sets the parent tag of `.entry-content` style as `style="height: 100%;"`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/8m33jafw/9/show/)** in full screen

Answer (score 0):

The 100% height is relative to the parent container. If your parent container stretches beyond the window height, so will the height of the child container.

I understood you want your section-header to have the viewport height. You have two alternatives: i) decouple your nested header into a standalone formation (as in your first fiddle) or ii) if you can't change the wrapping divs, as you have an unique identifier for the section you want to change the height, you can fix this problem by using jQuery, or javascript:

**JQuery:**

```
$('#section-headline').height($(window).height());
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8m33jafw/3/

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('section-headline').style.height = window.screen.availHeight + 'px';
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8m33jafw/5/

Comment: Thx denisol, I don't know about the downvotes. They are not from me, because I appreciate your answer. I tested the javascript and it works, but not as good as 100% css, because the height seems to be longer than the actual viewport which is especially visible when the view is resized. I'll work a little bit on it, and will be back for feedback, thx.

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness No worries. You can set the min-height instead of height if the content height can exceed the viewport height.